# Error while installing chatterBot

Tags: python, chatterbot

Whenever I try to install ChatterBot using command `pip install ChatterBot` it gives this error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003687898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/chatterbot/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chatterbot (from versi
ons: )
No matching distribution found for chatterbot
```

I downgraded from Python 3.6 to 2.7, yet receiving the same error.

I am using windows 8, Anaconda 2.7

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not installed required package. I think you need download them and install them before trying to install the chatterBot directly.
You can install using 'pip' or you can download and us 'python'.

> pip install path_where_you_have_downloaded_packages

or

> python path_where_you_have_downloaded_packages\setup.py install

Try it.

Answer (score 17):

Try this it will install:

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

Comment: Worked. Why is this comment so underrated?

Comment: the easiest way to tackle this problem, i have tried multiple version of python with different chatterbot and spacy version, nothing is compatible with this library.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not ChatterBot but the pip command.

Try install chatterbot from it's source:
https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/archive/master.zip

Then unzip the file.

After open up cmd and type in: `cd chatter_bot_master_directory`

Finally just type: `python(3) setup.py install`

If it doesn't work, retry it with more permission: Open up cmd in admin mode.

Comment: I tried to install in admin mode, I got this error
(C:\Anaconda2) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ChatterBot-master>python setup.py install
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-markdown/: ('_ssl.c:
645: The handshake operation timed out',) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools-markdown' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: ('_ssl.c:645: The handshake o
peration timed out',) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for setuptools-markdown.

Comment: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/tags

Answer (score 2):

It is a PIP installation Error!
ChatterBot can not be installed with PIP cmd.
For every module that can not be installed with PIP, Follow following procedure:

1) Download module from GITHUB or PyPi.

2) Unzip and place it in any Directory that you want to install module in.

3) In CMD: cd   ,where  is location where 'setup.py' of that module is located.

4) Now, CMD: python setup.py install

Module is now installed for use.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
pip install git+git://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git@master
```

or

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive issue, Try like this

> pip install --upgrade chatterbot

Comment: Hi Mallikarjunarao,
Still the same error.
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', po
rt=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/chatterbot-corpus/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chatterbot-corpus<1.0.
0,>=0.0.1 (from chatterbot) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for chatterbot-corpus<1.0.0,>=0.0.1 (from chatter
bot)

Comment: @SumantGK GK It seems to me Anaconda unable to get chatterbot-corpus, I will try to reproduce this issue on machine, The workaround you could do, Before installating chatterbot, could you try to install chatterbot-corups  `pip install --upgrade chatterbot-corpus`, then install `chatterbot pip install --upgrade chatterbot`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install pip for windows i.e. pipwin
So try--

```
pip install pipwin
```

then--

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

wait for a few moments as pipwin takes time to execute

then install pocketsphinx using

```
pipwin install pocketsphinx
```

then try

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python 3.7.4 in my case it works