# Error installing chatterbot, stuck on spacy

Tags: python, spacy, chatterbot

I try to install chatterbot, but there comes a time when it's in a loop to install spacy. appears written: 
`Using cached spacy-2.1.8.tar.gz (30.7 MB)` 
`Installing build dependencies ...` 
After waiting some time it returns 145 lines of errors. 
I already have spacy V3.2.1 installed, I don't know what else to do...

I using: 
Windows 11 
Python 3.9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install chatterbot from it's source: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/archive/master.zip

Then unzip the file.

After open up cmd and type in: cd chatter_bot_master_directory

Finally just type: python(3) setup.py install

[From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925395/error-while-installing-chatterbot)